# Saving the Date and Time on a Database server running in UK ignoring from where it is being requested to be saved

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, sql-server-2005

I have an excel add-in that reads values off of a spreadsheet and inserts them into the database. One of the values is a Date and Time which the Database table stores as a DateTime column. To read the date from the spreadsheet I use this method:

```
static internal DateTime GetContractDateFromExcelDate(string dateVal)
{
    double val = double.Parse(dateVal);
    DateTime contractDate = DateTime.FromOADate(val);
    return contractDate;
}
```

Then I add it to a datatable that has other columns and many such rows and do a bulk insert into a SQL server 2005 database running in the UK. Since I live on the US East Coast and the add-in runs from a US computer,it inserts the date and appends 05:00:00 to reflect the difference in the time between the US and UK. If I set the Web server time zone as Eastern Time this does not happen. How can I programmatically ensure that the date is uploaded to the database as Date and "00:00:00" instead of Date and "05:00:00".

Comment: Subtract 5 hours from the time extracted from the spreadsheet?

Comment: That would work, but it somewhat feels as a hack as opposed to forcing the server from acting smart and save what it is being asked to save. Come tomorrow, if the server is moved to a different location in another time zone? And the 20 days in November and March when the US is 6 hrs ahead of the UK since Daylight Saving begin late and end early in the UK?

Comment: I believe appending .Date to the end of `DateTime contractDate = DateTime.FromOADate(val);` will cause the value to only be the date component of the value and ignore the time component completely (meaning store 00:00:00 in SQL).  So, that line would be DateTime contractDate = DateTime.FromOADate(val).Date;

Answer (score 1):

Dates and times are a bit tricky as you have to always consider time zones.

If I understand correctly you are wanting to take the timezone aspect out of the equation.  So that when you upload the data it will not take into account the timezone from the source system.    What is interesting about your question is that UK I believe is GMT/UTC/Zulu time.  So it is what all other time zones are represented relative to.   In short though if you want to send data in a specific timezone, you should be able to do the following:

```
DateTime.SpecifyKind(contractDate, DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

It is key though that you understand time zones and their impact on the destination systems when persisting data.  http://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html